Linear transmission circuit for nuclear spectrometry
I have a linear transmission circuit that runs on a diode bridge. The bridge opens through the current generators I1, I2 and the input signal passes to the output. If you send a positive signal to the control signal 1 and a negative signal to the control signal 2, then there will be no transmission of the input signal (the transistors VT1, VT2 will close)
Question:
Why the transistor VT1 closes when the control signal is applied, and why the diodes VD1 and VD2 are needed


this frankly looks like you would just spend < 1€ on an analog switch IC and be done with it, rather than designing something less perfect out of discrete components. Why are you interested in this very hm, convoluted device? Your questions essentially depend on the resistor values, and you're not specifying these.

@MarcusMüller
This is a laboratory work at the university, I need to explain these questions to the teacher. To explain the principle of operation of the circuit, you do not need to know the values of the resistors (these are the words of the teacher)

In that case (this being your assignment): You need to say that, and state exactly how far you've gotten yourself, explain what you're stuck on, and what specific question you need to get an answer to, in order to be able to answer these questions yourself! Otherwise, your question is too broad.

@MarcusMüller I do not understand why the transistor VT1 closes when the control signal is applied, and I still do not understand why the diodes VD1 and VD2 are needed

Please edit your question post to be that one question!

VT1 closes because after applying the control signal 1&2 the VT3 carries the I1 current.
The VD1 avoids the EB breakdown of VT1. It can happen when VT1 emitter is going too low after applying the control signal 1&2.
